# Hide part of table header in responsive display

Tags: html, css

I have a table with table headers and naturally, table cells.

When in responsive mode, the table headers are displayed immediately above each table cell as a cell label, which is the desired display.

My issue is that there is additional text on the table header in desktop mode, which also displays in responsive mode.  I don't want that additional text to be part of the table cell label when responsive.

I've tried this:

```
<th valign="top"><div class="main">Occupancy date</div><div class="secondary">(Occupancy date must be within 6 weeks.)</div></th>
```

with CSS like this:

```
.main {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.secondary {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-style: italic;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
    .secondary {
        display: inline; 
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px){
    .secondary {
        display: none; 
    }
}
```

I also tried the divs as spans, and all sorts of media queries, but just can't get that additional text to hide on mobile.

I can't use Bootstrap (which I would much prefer to), as I'm stuck using forms from IBM WCM...

Does anyone have a suggestion?

The mobile display shows this as the table cell label:

```
<td class="input-wrapper" id="occupancy1"><h4 class="vheader">Occupancy date (Occupancy date must be within 6 weeks.): </h4>
```

I guess I have no idea how this is being put together.  There is no visible code to change this behavior.  I'd like to override it if at all possible.

Comment: `I don't want that additional text to be part of the table cell label when responsive.` I'm a bit confused - what exactly do you mean? Do you just want to hide it using `display: none`? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: The additional content is the text inside .secondary.  And yes, I do want to hide it, but for whatever reason, it won't hide.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question to include the full CSS, it's a bit more clear. That being said,  I don't believe the question has supplied enough information for us to formulate a substantial, well-informed answer. When I pasted your code [into a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n71asdw/), it works as expected. Do you have other CSS that could be overriding your `display: none`?

Comment: I just added the rendered html...if that helps.  I don't know what could be over-riding this.  Stupid IBM.